# Extract path in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How do I retrieve this: `123` from this: `123?arg=value#ancor`, in MYSQL; in other words, removing queries and removing anchors from the URL path.

Example scenario:

```
table1:
+----+------+
| id | path |
+----+------+
|  1 |  100 |
|  2 |  200 |
|  3 |  300 |
+----+------+

table2:
+----+----------------+
| id |           path |
+----+----------------+
|  1 |     100#anchor |
|  2 |  200?arg=value |
|  3 |      other/300 |
+----+----------------+

SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.path = revised_path(table2.path)

result:
+----+------+----+---------------+
| id | path | id |          path |
+----+------+----+---------------+
|  1 |  100 |  1 |    100#anchor |
|  2 |  200 |  2 | 200?arg=value |
+----+------+----+---------------+
```

UPDATE: Path will always be numeric, but can be any length.

UPDATE 2: revised_path() is a temporary replacement for the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Is the path always going to be 3 digits long?

Comment: no, but it will always be numeric

Comment: Is it always the only numeric part of the string?

Comment: Are you sure that is the output you want and what does revised_path do? from my understanding the output should include other/300 as well

Comment: @flightplanner - it's not always the only numeric part

Comment: @james_bond - revised_path() is a dummy text for which I'm looking a replacement for.

Comment: @james_bond - I need table1.path to equal the table2.path without anchors or queries, i.e. other/300 is not the same path as 300, while 100#anchor is the same path as 100

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the path is part of a URL. So the PHP function parse_url will do the trick.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.path = revised_path(table2.path)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_object)) {
    $path = parse_url($data->path);
}

// more code to diplay $path etc...
```

PHP documentation on [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: This needs to be done completely in MYSQL. table1 can only INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.path = table1.path, if table1.path is parsed in MYSQL.

Comment: Here is a like to an article where the user created an SQL function to return alpha/numeric values from fields. Good luck! - http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1280#815

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need to check if the path matches, but since one is contained within other data, you should check path (id) in table one is contained within path in table two, I would do it like this

```
SELECT table_1.id as t1_id,table_1.path as t1_path,
table_2.id as t2_id, table_2.path as t2_path
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2
WHERE INSTR(table_2.path,table_1.path) > 0
```

Edit:

This should give you the output you are asking for:

```
SELECT table_1.id as t1_id,table_1.path as t1_path,
table_2.id as t2_id, table_2.path as t2_path
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2
where table_1.path = cast(table_2.path as unsigned)
```

Comment: Very close! But this also INNER JOINs '200' and '200/somepath', which are not the same path.

Comment: From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast: The CAST() function takes an expression of any type and produces a result value of a specified type